# facebook register localhost fail

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, laravel, localhost

I'm trying to use facebook registration plugin on my localhost. But the problem is that the registration box won't show up.

Here are some screenshots:
https://dyp.im/FXwee52OJC

https://dyp.im/NRjFe2ulB9

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Facebook Login JavaScript Example</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>


            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.init({
                    appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
                    cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                    // the session
                    xfbml: true, // parse social plugins on this page
                    version: 'v2.0' // use version 2.0
                });




            };

            // Load the SDK asynchronously
            (function(d, s, id) {
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id))
                    return;
                js = d.createElement(s);
                js.id = id;
                js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

        </script>

<fb:registration redirect_uri="http://www.google.com" />
test

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try set your `App Domains` in https://developers.facebook.com to `localhost`? Your redirect_uri also needs to be within your site path, aka. http://localhost/continue-fb-registration

Comment: Thank you! changing the redirect_uri fixed my problem.

Comment: Right. Glad to hear it worked. I added a proper answer for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/v2.0), Facebook requires that the redirect_uri be within your own site:

> redirect_uri: The URI that will process the signed_request. It must be prefixed by your Site URL, defined in the app dashboard. This field is required.

So you need to change your registration tag to something like this:

```
<fb:registration redirect_uri="http://localhost/callback-fb-registered" />
```

Comment: Thank you that was the problem :)